# How to change HTML input type of label using Java or wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I wanted to know how I could change the input type of my Password field from "password" to "text" so that password no longer shows up as asterisks. I'm using Java and wicket in my project.

```
<div class="loginPassword">
    <label for="password"><wicket:message key="login.password"/></label>
    <input class="ft_login_password" wicket:id="password" type="password" name="password" />
</div>
```

The password field is set in my Java code as a PasswordTextField:

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.PasswordTextField;
PasswordTextField passwordField = new PasswordTextField("password");
```

Comment: Are you trying to create function that allows the user to show his password in clear text while entering? This is usually done client side with just Javascript code. eG: https://codepen.io/Sohail05/pen/yOpeBm - I'm not sure if having that functionality implemented via a wicket backend will really create a good user experience

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that site myself this morning. I was wondering if there was a way to do it with Java code or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments you should do this with JavaScript on the client side.

1. there is no point in making Ajax request to make the change on the server
2. Wicket will complain that PasswordTextField expects the `type` attribute to be `password`: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/837f3c137bf39f26ddc3b8e939235cde04e8c13d/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/PasswordTextField.java#L115

If you insist on doing it with Java then you will have to override `PasswordTextField#getInputTypes()` to return `new String[] {"password", "text"}`.

With Wicket/Java you should do something like:

```
passwordField = new PasswordTextField(...);
passwordField.setOutputMarkupId(true);

new AjaxLink<Void>("passwordToText") {
  @Override public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    passwordField.add(AttributeModifier.replace("type", "text"));
    target.add(passwordField);
  }
}
```